# centering tikz forest diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

I have a tikz/forest diagram that is almost complete, with a few remaining issues.
1a/1b: the title and the diagram are not aligned. I'd like them to be centered, so either the title needs to move right (solution 1a) or the diagram needs to shift left (solution 1b). What's the best way to go about this?
2: I'd like to first column in the diagram to either not appear, or be vertical. Is it possible?
3: How do you vary the minimum width by each column?(level?) The way I currently set it makes all levels the same width but there is different amount of text in each so this is not very efficient.

Please find below the screenshot and the code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\tikzset{mybrace/.style={decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm}, ultra thick, transform canvas={xshift=1mm}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Experimental Conditions and the Number of Observations}
\medskip

\newcommand*{\equal}{=}

% tier/.pgfmath=level()
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east, minimum width=28mm}
[
    [Versions, for tree={no edge, draw}[1p[1i[2p]]]
    ]
    [V1, no edge, for tree={forked edge, draw}
        [wwwww[rrr[wwwww (N{\equal}xx), name=A1][llllll (N{\equal}xx)]][uuuuu[wwwww (N{\equal}xx)][llllll (N{\equal}xx)]]]
        [llllll[rrr[wwwww (N{\equal}xx)][llllll (N{\equal}xx)]][uuuuu[wwwww (N{\equal}xx)][llllll (N{\equal}xx), name=B1]]]
    ]
    [V2, no edge, for tree={forked edge, draw}
        [wwwww[rrr[wwwww (N{\equal}xx), name=A2][llllll (N{\equal}xx)]][uuuuu[wwwww (N{\equal}xx)][llllll (N{\equal}xx)]]]
        [llllll[rrr[wwwww (N{\equal}xx)][llllll (N{\equal}xx)]][uuuuu[wwwww (N{\equal}xx)][llllll (N{\equal}xx), name=B2]]]
    ]
%    [V2, no edge, for tree={forked edge, draw}
%        [wwwww[rrr[A, name=A2][B]][uuuuu[A][B]]]
%        [llllll[rrr[A][B]][uuuuu[A][B, name=B2]]]
%    ]
]
\draw[mybrace] (A1.north east)--node[right=2mm]{V1}(B1.south east);
\draw[mybrace] (A2.north east)--node[right=2mm]{V2}(B2.south east);
\end{forest}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forest is shifted right because you have an invisible level 0, but it is still taking up space. Set `l sep=-5mm` for level 0 to compensate for the braces and brace labels and remove the `minimum width`. Then change the `minimum width` for levels other than the last.

Finally, use `for descendants` on the `V1` and `V2` nodes so they aren't drawn.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\tikzset{mybrace/.style={decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm}, ultra thick, transform canvas={xshift=1mm}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Experimental Conditions and the Number of Observations}
\medskip

\newcommand*{\equal}{=}

% tier/.pgfmath=level()
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east, if level=0{l sep=-5mm}{if n children=0{minimum width=28mm}{minimum width=15mm}}}
[
    [Versions, for tree={no edge, draw}[1p[1i[2p]]]
    ]
    [V1, no edge, for descendants={forked edge, draw}
        [wwwww[rrr[wwwww (N{\equal}xx), name=A1][llllll (N{\equal}xx)]][uuuuu[wwwww (N{\equal}xx)][llllll (N{\equal}xx)]]]
        [llllll[rrr[wwwww (N{\equal}xx)][llllll (N{\equal}xx)]][uuuuu[wwwww (N{\equal}xx)][llllll (N{\equal}xx), name=B1]]]
    ]
    [V2, no edge, for descendants={forked edge, draw}
        [wwwww[rrr[wwwww (N{\equal}xx), name=A2][llllll (N{\equal}xx)]][uuuuu[wwwww (N{\equal}xx)][llllll (N{\equal}xx)]]]
        [llllll[rrr[wwwww (N{\equal}xx)][llllll (N{\equal}xx)]][uuuuu[wwwww (N{\equal}xx)][llllll (N{\equal}xx), name=B2]]]
    ]
%    [V2, no edge, for tree={forked edge, draw}
%        [wwwww[rrr[A, name=A2][B]][uuuuu[A][B]]]
%        [llllll[rrr[A][B]][uuuuu[A][B, name=B2]]]
%    ]
]
\draw[mybrace] (A1.north east)--node[right=2mm]{V1}(B1.south east);
\draw[mybrace] (A2.north east)--node[right=2mm]{V2}(B2.south east);
\end{forest}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```